# How to export to folder

Tags: sketch-app

I want to export a group as PNG. I click Export, but I don't see a menu for choosing a folder, only a finite amount of some folders. How can I choose a folder?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the arrow to the right of the filename.